# How can I save device id's for push notifications - iOS

Tags: php, ios, sql, apple-push-notifications

I have a php script that sends notifications to a particular device token. I get my device token through the console in Xcode but when my app is published this is not true. How can I get the user's device token to put it in this script to send them push notifications. I have heard that you can use a database sever or something but I am quite a beginner with things like that so could you please provide a straightforward step-by step answer. Thanks

My Current Code:

```
<?php

// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = 'tokenfordevice1';

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = '*******';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'Message';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => ‘default’
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

EDIT: I have managed to get a SQL server running in LAMP. I now need to upload the deviceTokens into the server but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: As a suggestion, have a look at Parse.com - this may be easier for you

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to get the device token from the `AppDelegate` by using the below         function

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);
}
```

then `POST` or `GET` this token in your web service at server end. for example you use `GET` then use the below url:-

http://www.yourwebsite.com/push.php?deviceToken=yourdevicetoken&message=yourmessage

you can save the token in your `NSUserDefaults` so that you can get it anywhere in the app.

```
<?php

// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = $_REQUEST['devicetoken'];

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = '*******';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = $_REQUEST['message'];

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
'alert' => $message,
'sound' => ‘default’
);

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
   echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
   echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Ok. I have that line of code that gets the device token. Can you explain how I can put this onto my web server and what I need to do. Thanks

Comment: Use this at your web service end to get device token from the URL
`$deviceToken = $_REQUEST['devicetoken']` and also for the message so that the variable you send in url place in those and send this while you are sending the mesaage. In the above url device token and message are variables and the value after = is your variable you want to send.

Comment: Thanks for that. How can I gather the device token from users who are using my app without needing to go into their NSLOG files. So how can I `POST` or `GET` this on my web server.

Comment: Save the device token in the `NSuserDefault` when someone post the message just put the token form the userdefaults into your url parameter and `GET` at the web service by using above php script. So for every new device user save its own device token in the userdefauls.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean by that. What I want to do is allow users to 'subscribe' to a train station and give them notifications when trains are scheduled to arrive at that station. I am quite a beginner developer with push notifications so excuse me for asking so many questions.

Comment: So when the user want to subscribe, are you making request to a web service with url?

Comment: I will send the device ID to the service and have different php scripts for the different stations. The device id will hopefully be put in a folder for that particular station and the php script will look for device ids in that folder. Is this possible?

Comment: You are required to send the device token from the device to the web service. At your server database make table for the user where you save the device token for a specific user and stations he subscribed. When you want to send notifications to the user just get device token for that user and station from that table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55268/discussion-between-isaacm-and-manpreet-singh).

Comment: Sorry I am not sure if i was clear. The device tokens would be uploaded to a folder on the web service and the php script would look in this folder for tokens and send to all of them

Comment: Hi I am available again on TeamViewer